# OS X Mavericks doesn't start decryption after password entered

Tags: macos, login, osx-mavericks, decryption

I'm having some issues with my MacBook Pro. Last week I found the computer with a gray background with a folder symbol with a question mark in the middle. I couldn't do anything with the computer so I rebooted and tested the drive, and no failure was found. The disk was also successfully found.

Today it started acting unresponsive and Spotlight didn't show files or applications. I used Onyx to test the drive again and nothing was found. After some cleaning with Onyx the computer was restarted but after I enter the password nothing happens. I've had the gray Apple on the screen for several minutes. Usually it starts to decrypt the drive but not anymore :/.

Any suggestions on how to solve the problem would be appreciated. I'm getting a bit nervous that something is seriously wrong.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

The problem was due to FileVault being corrupted. I managed to solve it by rebooting to recovery. I repaired all drives, and turned off the encryption. So far so good, everything seems to be back to normal :)